# Parse multiple of the same key JSON simple java

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I'm not an expert at JSON so I'm not sure if I'm missing something obviously. But, what I'm trying to do is to parse this:

```
[{"name":"Djinnibone"},{"name":"Djinnibutt","changedToAt":1413217187000},{"name":"Djinnibone","changedToAt":1413217202000},{"name":"TEsty123","changedToAt":1423048173000},{"name":"Djinnibone","changedToAt":1423048202000}]
```

I don't want to get Djinnibone only the rest of the names following it. What I've managed to create is this. It give the right number of names. but they are all null. In this case null,null,null,null .

```
public String getHistory(UUID uuid) throws Exception {
    String history = "";
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/"+uuid.toString().replace("-", "")+"/names").openConnection();
    JSONArray response = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    for(int index = 1; index < response.size(); index++) {
        jsonObject.get(response.get(index));
        String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
        if(index < response.size()) {
            history = history + name + ",";
        } else {
            history = history + name + ".";
        }
    }
    return history == "" ? history = "none." : history;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you're getting each `JSONObject` from the array but you're not using it correctly. You simply need to change your code like this in order to extract each object and use it directly, no need for an intermediate `JSONObject` creation:

```
public String getHistory(UUID uuid) throws Exception {
    String history = "";
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/"+uuid.toString().replace("-", "")+"/names").openConnection();
    JSONArray response = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    for(int index = 1; index < response.size(); index++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = response.get(index);
        String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
        if(index < response.size()) {
            history = history + name + ",";
        } else {
            history = history + name + ".";
        }
    }
    return history == "" ? history = "none." : history;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping mean learn a little bit more about JSON. One thing you forgot though is to cast response.get(index); to JSONObject.             JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) response.get(index);

Comment: Glad to help! Good point about the casting. I wasn't sure which JSON library you were using. Some don't require any casting because `JSONArray.get()` will return a `JSONObject`, some provide a `JSONArray.getJSONObject()` method that doesn't require a cast and some other libraries do require an explicit cast.